# Photoshop Filter in Compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes

Is it possible to use Photoshop filters from inside the Blender compositor? Just thought it was an interesting challenge that somebody out there may have solved? Of course I can run batch filter on rendered frames - but think it would be nice to see live effects.

Thanks.

Comment: It _is_ possible to replicate most PS filters in the compositor with a combination of nodes, blur, noise etc.

Comment: Yep, as iKIsR said, many PS filters can be "reproduced" via the powerful node compositor. Some are directly supported, such as blur, sharpen, etc. While others, such as halftones, need a bit more complex settings. However, if you succeed in making them, you can save the setting as a single Node Group for the future use. :)

Answer (score 3):

**No**, As far as I know, nobody has done this before.

Even if this was done it wouldn't be cross platform (since Photoshop plugins are compiled AFAIK).

Comment: There have been applications that implemented the host API before (Eyeon's Digital Fusion does it, for example), but it hasn't been done for Blender.  Even if you did, most Photoshop plugins only work with 8 bit color, and they would indeed be platform specific.

Comment: Sure, its possible to do, its just not been done (AFAIK).